# Would it be okay to use the Amazon S3 for personal use?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud-storage, amazon-web-services, online-backup

I understand that AWS is meant for corporate use, but I just thought about using the S3 for personal backups, and by using their calculator it seems like it would be quite cheap in comparison to other services like Dropbox and Google Drive.

Do you think Amazon would allow this, or is it a stupid idea?

Comment: As long as you pay and don't do anything illegal they couldn't care less.

Comment: Sure, go ahead, The Amazon S3 police won't come and get you. Seriously.

Comment: Dropbox stores your data on S3. [All files stored online by Dropbox are encrypted and kept securely on Amazon's Simple Storage Service (S3) in multiple data centers located across the United States.](https://www.dropbox.com/help/7/en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will allow it. I currently use Amazon S3 through [Jungledisk](https://www.jungledisk.com) for backups.  I can use it for sharing as well, but I have enough free space on dropbox I use dropbox more often (simpler UI).

Comment: and there are many more S3 front ends besides jungle disc, better also....http://ijaar.com/amazon-s3-tools/